# Opening a floating window in electron that is visible on all workspaces with window.open

Tags: macos, electron

I am trying to open a window from my electron app that will float on top of other full screen apps

So from inside my electron application I call

```
openPauseWindow() {
  const options = [
    "width=600",
    "height=300",
    "frame=no",
    "transparent=yes",
    "alwaysOnTop=yes",
    "visibleOnAllWorkspaces=yes",
    "hasShadow=no"
  ].join(",");

  window.open("/apps/appoverlay/", "overlay", options);
}
```

which opens a floating window, but when I go into fullscreen in another app, my floating window disappears. I though `visibleOnAllWorkspaces=yes` should fix that.

I am on macOS, it seems that may also be an issue (?)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `window.open`, try creating a `BrowserWindow` using `electron.remote`

Like this:

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote

let win = new BrowserWindow({ 
  width: 600, 
  height: 300,
  frame: false,
  transparent: true,
  alwaysOnTop: true,
  visibleOnAllWorkspaces: true,
  hasShadow: false
})

win.loadURL('/apps/appoverlay/')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the bellow code

```
const { remote } = require('electron');
stopScreenShareWin = new remote.BrowserWindow({ 
                width: 400, 
                height: 40,                     
                show:true, 
                alwaysOnTop:true, 
                frame: false,
                titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
                visibleOnAllWorkspaces:true , 
                webPreferences: {
                    nodeIntegration: true
                }
            });
stopScreenShareWin.loadFile('calls/screenshare-overlay.html');
```

to stop this window

```
if(stopScreenShareWin){
  stopScreenShareWin.close();
  stopScreenShareWin=null;
}
```

you can avoid visibleOnAllWorkspaces:true

It will look something like

[image]